# converting a serialized json from new format to old format

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have a serialized json in good format, but trying to do deserializejson in the coldfusion format version 8 and before > possible?
i looked at the docs, checked the custom serializer etc and other values but they do not seem to be working as what i am trying to do here
any idea how can i do this

Did some what a try but i am getting confused

```
<cfscript>
       myStruct = {a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5};
       myKeyList=myStruct.keyList();
       WriteOutput(myKeyList);
</cfscript>

<cffunction name="NewJSOntoOldJSON" returntype="any" output="false">
        <cfargument name="sData" required="true" type="any">
        <cfscript>
            var oldJSON = { "COLUMNS" : };
            var arrofColumns = ListtoArray(sData.keyList());
            for (arrofColumn in arrofColumns) {
                arrayAppend(oldJSON, arrofColumn);
            }
            writedump(oldJSON);
        </cfscript>
        <cfreturn oldJSON>
    </cffunction>
    
    <cfdump var="#NewJSOntoOldJSON(myStruct)#">
```

Comment: Are you using CF8 or earlier? I ask because if you are using a version of CF that old, you are begging for more problems than just how to hack modern JSON into an old format. CF8 is ancient and really should be upgraded. And to be honest, any hardware that is able to run CF8 should probably be looked at, too. It will require some work to modernize, but much less work than when the script kiddies with Metasploit have destroyed your site.

Comment: Also, CF's handling of JSON was very sub-par before, I think, CF11 or 2016, So you may be trying to run yourself into a circle that is already broken.

Comment: And last, your code above isn't doing what you're trying to make it do. `{ "COLUMNS": }` isn't valid, because you don't give it a value. Your `arrayAppend` is invalid because `oldJSON` is a `struct` and not an `array`.  Look at the data structure you want to end up with and fit your existing data into that.

Comment: want to end from new structure too old, i know and i am using it, but there is a big pile of code which is using old format and working well, in that scenario, i do want to change it, totally understand what you are mentioning here, but some lack of time, i need to make the new json format to old deserialization technique so i can make code work.

Comment: What exactly is the "old" format? Show us an example so we can understand how it differs from this "new" format.

Comment: I am looking at this: `{"ROWCOUNT":2, "COLUMNS":["CITY","STATE"],"DATA":{"City":["Newton","San
Jose"],"State":["MA","CA"]}}`

Comment: or this https://trycf.com/gist/8769e325de51b985c9bfad6359eb2446/lucee5?theme=monokai but this missing rowcount, which i need to add